Wordpress Site Editor. I cannot find out why the Navigation menu is visible throughout site editor but not on public site
Twenty twenty four theme. I am creating a new website. I have previously changed 3 websites to this Theme but for this website I cannot get the menu to display on the public site which is https://aframjavea.com/. The menu is rendered as expected on all the pages in the site editor including the previews.
Here is the code for the Header Template
<!-- wp:group {"align":"full","className":"wc-blocks-pattern-header-large wc-blocks-header-pattern","style":{"spacing":{"padding":{"right":"40px","left":"40px","top":"24px","bottom":"24px"}}},"layout":{"type":"default"}} -->
<div class="wc-blocks-pattern-header-large wc-blocks-header-pattern wp-block-group alignfull" style="padding-top:24px;padding-right:40px;padding-bottom:24px;padding-left:40px"><!-- wp:group {"align":"full","layout":{"type":"default"}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group alignfull"><!-- wp:columns {"verticalAlignment":"center","isStackedOnMobile":false,"align":"full"} -->
<div class="wp-block-columns alignfull are-vertically-aligned-center is-not-stacked-on-mobile"><!-- wp:column {"verticalAlignment":"center","width":"70%","layout":{"type":"default"}} -->
<div class="wp-block-column is-vertically-aligned-center" style="flex-basis:70%"><!-- wp:group {"layout":{"type":"flex","flexWrap":"nowrap","justifyContent":"left"}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group"><!-- wp:site-logo {"shouldSyncIcon":true} /-->

<!-- wp:site-title /--></div>
<!-- /wp:group --></div>
<!-- /wp:column -->

<!-- wp:column {"verticalAlignment":"center","width":""} -->
<div class="wp-block-column is-vertically-aligned-center"><!-- wp:group {"style":{"spacing":{"blockGap":"0px"}},"layout":{"type":"flex","flexWrap":"nowrap","justifyContent":"right"}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group"><!-- wp:woocommerce/customer-account {"displayStyle":"icon_only","iconStyle":"line","iconClass":"wc-block-customer-account__account-icon"} /-->

<!-- wp:woocommerce/mini-cart /--></div>
<!-- /wp:group --></div>
<!-- /wp:column --></div>
<!-- /wp:columns --></div>
<!-- /wp:group -->

<!-- wp:group {"align":"full","layout":{"type":"flex","flexWrap":"nowrap","justifyContent":"space-between"}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group alignfull"><!-- wp:navigation {"ref":126} /-->

<!-- wp:group {"style":{"spacing":{"padding":{"right":"0","left":"0"}}},"layout":{"type":"constrained"}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group" style="padding-right:0;padding-left:0"><!-- wp:search {"label":"","showLabel":false,"placeholder":"Search","buttonText":"Search","buttonUseIcon":true,"query":{"post_type":"product"},"style":{"border":{"radius":"0px"}}} /--></div>
<!-- /wp:group --></div>
<!-- /wp:group --></div>
<!-- /wp:group -->


And this is the appearance in the site editor
enter image description here
I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction
I have tried moving the navigation block within the Header, changing the Navigation settings and disabling plugins.

The problem seems to be caused by some corruption introduced by the YITH Theme which I used briefly. Correct menu entries can only be created by using the + when editing the menu block in full screen
